# Why do click and open reports show times in UTC rather than the site's timezone?

Tags: civimail, civireport, php, timezone

The mailing and click tracking reports are showing times in UTC. There is no PHP MySQL timezone mismatch - and `mysql -e 'select now()'` and `date` return the right times - as per timezone.

Comment: Having the same issue.
Another thing I noticed is that when I create contribution pages and set ending date it ends 8 hours early...
Set time zone in PHP correct and set timezone in WP CMS correct...
It's really annoying.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! You have posted this as an answer, but it doesn't appear to answer the original question.  If the other answer doesn't help and/or you have a different question you would be better off posting this as a new question.  This isn't a forum and you are unlikely to get answers if you post here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mailing clicks and opens are registered via scripts in extern (which are quite old) - and don't appear to use the cms environment - as such if the timezone isn't set for php and has defaulted to UTC - this won't show in the warnings - despite it being the issue. To detect this compare the result of php  To confirm this is the problem run

```
php -r 'echo date_default_timezone_get() . PHP_EOL;'
```

if the result is UTC - then you can fix by setting the date.timezone value correctly in your php.ini or similar file.

This won't resolve historical data but will mean clicks and opens in the future are recorded in the correct timezone.